# Convert string into array of matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, string, matrix, substring

It is required to develop a program to do Matrix operations. The program use
a defined string format to represent the matrix in the user input and output
sections. For the following matrix:
examplee : the user input the string representation of the Matrix :
ex:[10 2.13 3;-5 0 4;16.5 1 8]
In the program, the user enters a matrix in the defined string format then
asked to enter an operator

so i can't convert this string to an array to make operations as sum or multiply

```
using namespace std;

int main() { 

    int i, j, n; 
    string s1; 
    float m1[100][100]; 

    getline(cin, s1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
        for (n = 0; n < s1.length(); n++) { 
            if (isspace(s1.at(i)));
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: the number of spaces is fixed ? Are you tring to parse data read from a file ?

Comment: It is required to develop a program to do Matrix operations. The program use
a defined string format to represent the matrix in the user input and output
sections. For the following matrix:
the string representation of the Matrix is :
[10 2.13 3;-5 0 4;16.5 1 8]
In the program, the user enters a matrix in the defined string format then
asked to enter an operator
i have the problem that i can't convert this string to an array 2D To make these operation

Comment: when you say you want " take all values before space in string until the previous space " does this refer to reading a single value of `[10 2.13 3;-5 0 4;16.5 1 8]` ? eg `10` ? Note that `10` has no space in front.

Comment: if you want to parse (= read the numbers from) `[10 2.13 3;-5 0 4;16.5 1 8]` then please include that in your question. The question should contain input and expected output anyhow and it is currently not clear how your code relates to `[10 2.13 3;-5 0 4;16.5 1 8]`

Comment: sorry for that.. i just edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: I don't understand your nested loops. There is only one loop necessary to iterate over string. Reading char for char, you may have a `switch` where `' '` increments column, `';'` increments row and resets column to 0, `']'` finishs reading of matrix, `'0'` ... `'9'`, `'.'`, `'-'`, etc. are collected. Before incrementing row, column, or finishing, collected characters should be converted (e.g. with `strtod()`) and stored at current matrix element.

Comment: i made first for loop for row and second one to test the string index to watch where the space and then supstring the values before each space but i can't put it in codes :( if there are another method pls tell me @Scheff

Comment: I told you already another method. Didn't get it?

Comment: no :( can you explain it moree

Answer (score 1):

One algorithm to parse / read matrices like

> `[10 2.13 3;-5 0 4;16.5 1 8]`

could be:

1. Indices `col` and `row` are initialized with `0`.
2. A loop which skips characters of the input string until a `'['` is found.
3. A loop which reads the input string character for character with the following handling

   - `'0'`, `'1'`, ... , `'9'`, `'+'`, `'-'`, `'.'`, `'e'`, `'E'`: collect character (It's part of a number.)
   - `' '`: If there are collected characters, convert them to a `float` (e.g. using `strtod()`), store the result in matrix element (`row`, `col`), and increment `col` afterwards.
   - `';'`: If there are collected characters, convert them to a `float` (e.g. using `strtod()`), store the result in matrix element (`row`, `col`).
     Increment `row` and reset `col` to `0`.
   - `']'`: If there are collected characters, convert them to a `float` (e.g. using `strtod()`), store the result in matrix element (`row`, `col`).
     Reading of this matrix is done.
   - Everything else is a syntax error.

Notes:

- [`strtod()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) has a second argument which returns a pointer to first not-accepted character. This should be checked whether it points to end of collected characters. (Otherwise, the algorithm may accept e.g. `"1.23+1"` as `1.23` without noticing the syntax error at `+`.
- The above algorithm could/should also return the number of rows and columns collected.
- Whenever a new row is started, the columns should/could be checked before whether the previous row was ful. (This excludes the first row which actually defines how many columns are there.)
- The maximum possible number of rows and columns should be considered as well as a two-dim. C array is used.